# Disable CSS HTML Snippet Previewer

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm looking to disable the CSS HTML Previewer but I'm not sure how to do so. What I'm referring to looks like this:

[image]

I thought it was emmet but after adding the exception to my preferences and restarting my editor it still appears:

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    "markdown",
    "css"
],
```

How can I remove the HTML Snippet Previewer?